# Can I run multiple HttpAsyncClients with one PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to create multiple `HttpAsyncClient` with a single connection manager (similar to the [the example in the Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management#multiple)).

The problem is that this does not seem to work with the `HttpAsyncClient` (only with the `HttpClient`). The application fails with the following errors in the log:

```
14:00:56.443 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - I/O reactor terminated abnormally
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal state ACTIVE
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:46)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Request execution cancelled
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.getResult(BasicFuture.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:70)
    at com.example.Test.main(Test.java:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Request execution cancelled
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:92)
    at com.example.Test.main(Test.java:31)
```

This is the code I am running:

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.IOReactorConfig;
import org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ConnectingIOReactor;
import org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOReactorException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ConnectingIOReactor ioReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig.custom().build());
        PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(ioReactor);
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient client1 = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
                .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                .build();
        client1.start();
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient client2 = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
                .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .build();
        client2.start();

        var res1 = client1.execute(new HttpGet("https://www.google.com"), null);
        res1.get();
        var res2 = client2.execute(new HttpGet("https://www.google.com"), null);
        res2.get();
    }
}
```

I use the version 4.4.15 of https://hc.apache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell both builders that the connection manager is shared:

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client1 = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(connManager)
        .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
        .build();
client1.start();
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client2 = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(connManager)
        // do not call setConnectionManagerShared on the first client, only on all others sharing the same connManager
        .setConnectionManagerShared(true) 
        .build();
client2.start();
```

Comment: I have tried that - no Exceptions but the applications hangs in line `res1.get();`

Comment: seems like you either need to manage the connection manager on your own or only call setConnectionManagerShared on one client: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPASYNC-83